# Conditional background image in header

Tags: conditional-statements, background-image

I'm trying to modify the content-header of a website, so it will display a custom background image for the search result page and for single posts of a post type. Here's the current working code:

```
<div class="single__header" <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
echo 'style="background-image: url(\'';
the_post_thumbnail_url('post-background'); 
echo '\'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"';
}
?>>
```

And this what I've come up with:

```
<div class="single__header" 
<?php if (is_page_template('single-perspactive-funding.php')) {
        echo 'style="background-image: url([website-url-hidden]/content/uploads/2018/04/single-funding-header.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"';
}
?>
<?php elseif (is_search()) {
        echo 'style="background-image: url([website-url-hidden]/content/uploads/2018/04/Header-image_Notfound.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"';
}
?>
<?php else : ?>
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
            echo 'style="background-image: url(\'';
            the_post_thumbnail_url('post-background'); 
            echo '\'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"';
          }
          ?>
<?php endif; ?>>
```

But for some reason this isn't working, the header and the rest of the page is no longer loading.

I'm probably doing something wrong, but don't know exactly what. So any help is appreciated.

**Maybe it's because the single funding is a post type and not a page?** So maybe I have to change 'if (*is_page_template*('single-perspactive-funding.php'))' into something else?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your syntax, it is recommended to enable error printing in the development phase.
Your code is something like

```
<?php
// Some code ...
   <?php
   // you cannot have php inside php
   ?>
?>
```

I have tried to fix the syntactical errors in below code

```
<div class="single__header" 
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    $bgsearch = 'style="background-image: url([website-url]/content/uploads/2018/04/Header-image_Notfound.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"';
    $bgdefault = 'style="background-image: url(\''.the_post_thumbnail_url('post-background').'\'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"'; 

    if (is_search()) {
        echo $bgsearch;
    } else {
        echo $bgdefault;
    }    
}

?>
>
    Div contents
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still something seems to be missing; with this code no header image is coming up. 

I'v chosen to put the desired header image in the search.php template, that works fine now.

Thanks again for your help!