# Use array of background-image urls

Tags: url, background-image

In the template of a post type I have a custom header part, in which I want to display multiple background images. This is the current code for a single image:

```
<div class="single__header" style="background-image: url(../content/uploads/2018/04/fundings-header.jpg); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover;">
```

How can I use/load more than one url, to randomly display a different background images? After much searching I found [this solution](http://apexlogic.net/code-bank/php/random-background-images-with-css-and-php/), but somehow I can't get it working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's not working? Can you post the code of your attempt so they we can help?

Comment: @Benoît: I get an error, so maybe something in the code of the solution (please follow the link in my post above) is not right. I have also tried this: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49823392/conditional-background-image-in-header

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Benoît: if I replace the background URL in my header template part with `background: url(<?php include'functions.php'; displayBackground();?>)`, every page that uses a template with `<?php get_template_part('components/content/content','header'); ?>` does not show the header or any content, only the logo/menu section at the the top. If I use it in the post template, I get a 500 error. So I guess something in the code of the solution is not right, maybe how the 'include' statement is used? BTW: I did add a background.php file with the code to 'includes' folder and to 'functions.php'.

Comment: Can you edit your question above to show us the code of your 2 files?

Answer (score 0):

Ther's no need for an extra php file.
Here's a more elegant solution:

```
<?php
$imagesDir = 'images/'; //path to your images directory    
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);    
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)]; 
?>
<div class="single__header" style="background-image: url(<?= $randomImage ?>); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover;">
    Test
</div>
```